# How to configure web service binding to serve both request http and https request?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, web-config, wcf-binding

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Complete_Html5.CompleteService.CompleteServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior" name="Complete_Html5.CompleteService.Complete">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Complete" contract="Complete_Html5.CompleteService.Complete" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
      <service name="Complete_Html5.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="Complete_Html5.Service1ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Complete_Html5.Service1" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Complete_Html5.Service1AspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="Complete_Html5.CompleteService.CompleteServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>      
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Complete_Html5.CompleteService.CompleteServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>        
        <behavior name="Complete_Html5.Service1ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>        
      </serviceBehaviors>      
    </behaviors>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Complete" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="10485760" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />

          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Complete1" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Service1" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="10485760" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true" messageEncoding="Text">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Service11" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://www.examplete.com:83/CompleteService/Complete.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Complete" contract="Complete_Html5.CompleteService.Complete" name="BasicHttpBinding_Complete" />
      <endpoint address="http://www.examplete.com:83/CompleteService/Complete.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Complete1" contract="PMCService.Complete" name="BasicHttpBinding_Complete1" />
      <endpoint address="http://www.examplete.com:83/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Service1" contract="ReportService.Service1" name="BasicHttpBinding_Service1" />
      <endpoint address="http://www.examplete.com:83/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Service11" contract="ReportService.Service1" name="BasicHttpBinding_Service11" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Above is the `service` setting in `web.config` what changes I have to make so that I could use both hits `http` and `https` while accessing `website`??

We have added ssl certificate to server and have unchecked `required ssl` from website `ssl` certificate setting.

[image]
 It it working fine `http` but when hits come is website is with `https` it's throwing error as:

> The provided URI scheme `https` is invalid; Expected `http`. Parameter
>   name: via.

How to solve this so that allow both hits `http` and `https`?

> This is specially when we calling web service.

Have tried by adding `httpsGetEnabled="true"` in serviceMetadata element but still not working..!

I have tried by just adding security mode to `Transport` but still not working.
I think it could be wrong setting. How to do that binding by proper way?